# Pass a Value from Button to Text Field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to pass a number to a text field on button click. User hits "add to cart" and the 2499 is added to the total already in the text field.

```
<form name="cart">
    <input id="display" type="text" name="output" size="6" placeholder="0000"/>
<button id="scart" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addCart()" +='2499'"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

var total=""

function addCart(){
    document.getElementById('scart').value;
    total+= document.getElementById('display').value;
    console.log(total);
}

</script>
```

When learning, I feel that I understand the logic, but don't know the syntax.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make an "add to cart" button on a fake store site. When the button is clicked the 2499 gets added to the total and is displayed.

Comment: so when I click the button it will add 2499 to the input ??

Comment: The idea is for the total to be displayed.

Comment: ok cool @SonnyBonds Please review my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I made a codepen for you:  https://codepen.io/NeilGBK/pen/boGadz?editors=1111

```
   <form name="cart">
        <input id="display" type="text" name="output" size="6" placeholder="0000"/>   
    </form>
    <button id="scart" onclick="addCart(2499)">Add To Cart</button>

<script>
    function addCart(v){
        document.getElementById('display').value = v
        console.log(v);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

I'm passing the number to the function and simply using that to change the value of the input. I'm also logging it to the console

Comment: Thank you (and everyone else) for your help. I've got a lot to learn. I'm in a JS class now and am most likely going to a coding bootcamp next month. I'm trying to learn all I can, but it's been difficult.

Comment: We've all been there. One thing you should familiarize yourself with is the concept of function scoping. Most popular languages are "block-scoped", but JS is function-scoped. You assumed that the variable total was accessible from within the addCart() function, which is how it would work in a block scoped language. One way to do what you were attempting is to use a closure. However, pure functions are more predictable. That probably all sounds like Greek to you right now, but those concepts will come into play soon. When those concepts make sense you'll be on your way to mastering JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors, your quotes are not matching and you don't have closing button tag. Also, why don't you add 2499 in the code?

How about this:

```
<form name="cart">
    <input id="display" type="text" name="output" size="6" placeholder="0000"/>
    <button id="scart" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addCart()" > 
    </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var total=""

    function addCart(){
        document.getElementById('scart').value;
        total+= document.getElementById('display').value + 2499;
        console.log(total);
    }

    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do so I made the beginning of a "cart" button where the input is the quantity you want to add to cart.

I then print out the number typed in and the total if you pressed the button more than once.

```html
<input id="display" type="text" name="output" size="6" placeholder="0000" />
<button id="scart" type="button">Add to cart</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var total = 0;
  var display = document.querySelector('#display');
  var scart = document.querySelector('#scart');

  scart.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var str = display.value;
    var num = parseInt(str, 10);
    console.log('You entered the number: ', num);
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      total += num;
    }
    console.log('The total is now: ', total);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that is wrong here:

First, replace `+` with a good indicator `data-value` or whatever

```
<button id="scart" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addCart()" data-value="2499"/>
```

Second, In your script you should make `var total` a `number` not `string`.

```
var total = 0;
```

Finally, your `addCart()` function.

```
function addCart() {
    // I see you are trying to get the value of the clicked button so you need to store it as this does not do anything
    // document.getElementById('scart').value;
    var value = document.getElementById('scart').value;
    // Add it to total var;, you need to parseInt it as .value returns string
    total += parseInt(value);
    // put it on display
    document.getElementById('display').value = total;
}
```

Hope that helps.